# Angular 10 reset textarea that was filled with an async pipe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

This feels like a weird one. I'm filling a textarea with the contents of an API call through Observable | async and everything works fine, except I'm not really sure how to reset the field to the original data if the user cancels the modal or clicks the reset button.

The field:

```
<textarea (ngModelChange)="jsonChanged($event)" [ngModel]="(data$ | async)?.characteristics | json"></textarea>
```

I suppose setting a property in the component and using that as the model would work but I'd like to continue to use the async, as I don't really want to subscribe to the data observable in the component (for ease of unsubscribing and because it's set inside another subscription that i've had some difficulty composing with rxjs operators. :)

Comment: When you detect you want to reset, do this try  this.data$= of("Deafult");  FYI, the $event is the ngModel.ViewModel value. I wrote about ngModel, and pipes here:  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Comment: @JohnPeters Sorry to be thick, but can you elaborate a little? TS is complaining about assigning a string to my observable, which observes a specific data format. I also tried assigning this.data$ to the original observable but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: @JohnPeters also just tried: `this.data$ = of(this.query.select(this.slug)).pipe(mergeAll())` (putting the original observable into the `of()` but that didn't work either. I was able to get a change by using `of("Default")` and setting `data$: Observable<any>` but all it really did was blank out my form field because it's made to handle a json object and not a string.

Comment: You're already removing subscriptions and replacing it by async pipes. Go one step further and use smart/presentation components, with input setters when needed. You won't have this kind of problem : all the pipes will be at the smart level and all the html and presentation logic will be in the presentation components and using only variables.

Comment: This may help https://dev.to/jwp/observables-as-event-engines-2f7p